# Merge multiple array .map into a single one

Tags: javascript

I have a array of javascript objects

```
var arr =  [ 
        { 
          query_result_id: 25,
          author_email: 'john@example.com'
        },
       { 
          query_result_id: 28,
          author_email: 'eric@example.com'
        },
  ]
```

I am using `.map` to enter new values on each javascript object

```
arr
        .map( s => s["status"] = "dev")
        .map( s => s["customer_id"] = customerId)
        .map( s => s["email_nb"] = emailId)
        //and so on for about 10 new key/values
```

the output is:

```
 var arr =  [ 
            { 
              query_result_id: 25,
              author_email: 'john@example.com',
              status: dev,
              customer_id: 45,
              email_nb: 45
            },
           { 
              query_result_id: 28,
              author_email: 'eric@example.com',
              status: dev,
              customer_id: 78,
              email_nb: 56
            },
      ]
```

Is it possible in javascript to not chain 10 `.map` but instead one single operation to make it cleaner and maybe even more performant/faster ?

Comment: Just add all object to s at once and return it later.

Comment: sorry but how do you do this ?

Comment: Where is the data that you are adding?  Is it also an array of objects?

Comment: `arr = arr.map(s => { s.status = 'a'; s.customer_id = 'b'; return s; });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you intend to keep the same values inside the array you shouldn't use map.

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is intended to recreate a new array with values depending on source array. What you want to do is to apply a function on each element that's what [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is made for

here's how you can do it using foreach :

```js
let customerId = "customerId"
let emailId = "emailId"

var arr =  [{query_result_id: 25,author_email: 'john@example.com'},
            {query_result_id: 28,author_email: 'eric@example.com'}]

arr.forEach( s => {
  s["status"] = "dev"
  s["customer_id"] = customerId
  s["email_nb"] = emailId
})
        
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Although other answers suggest .map is possible i understand the underlying concept better now of .map ot change sth and .forEach to add new elements. thanks

Comment: forEach is not to add new element, it is to loop over the element without changing the array itself (here since the elements are object we can modify them without touching the array)

Answer (score 0):

For each object, you can create a new object by re-using the old one's properties/values using the spread operator, and adding the other properties/values to this new object literal:

```
arr = arr.map(s => (
  {...s, status : "dev", customer_id : customerId, email_nb : emailId}
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, for example like this:

```
arr.map(s => {
         s["status"] = "dev";
         s["customer_id"] = customerId;
         s["email_nb"] = emailId;

         return s;
    });
```

Always keep in mind, that this:

```
arr.map(x => x + 1);
```

Is just a shorthand for this:

```
arr.map(x => {
   return x + 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you don't have to chain map for every change you are making to your data.  Do all of the all of the changes in the body of the map's callback, and then return the object.

```
let data = arr.map(entry => {
    entry["something"] = otherData["something"];
    entry["something else"] = otherData["something-else"];
    // etc. for all of the keys
    // now the entry is entirely transformed, you can return it
    return entry;
})
```